# want to show correct Li element based on some conditions

Tags: jquery, html

i have html like this :
ul have few li elements, with remove button,

question is :  i need to show correct li element with CheckMark Image sign,

let's say i am calling ShowCheckMarkLi(Descriptions,Client)

then only 2 li should be display in UL element with CheckmarkImage.Ico other should be gone away

html is like this :-

```
   <ul>
            <li id="liRightDescriptions">
                <span>
                    <span>Descriptions</span>
                    <img class="removeImg" src="../Images/RemoveButton.ico" /></span>
            </li>
            <li id="liRightSpecialization">
                <span><span>Specialization</span><img style="display: none;" class="removeImg" src="../Images/RemoveButton.ico" /></span>
            </li>
            <li id="liRightOrgChart">
                <span>Org Chart</span><img style="display: none;" class="removeImg" src="../Images/RemoveButton.ico" />
            </li>
            <li id="liRightClient"><span>
                <span>Client</span>
                <img style="display: none;" class="removeImg" src="../Images/RemoveButton.ico" /></span></li>
            <li id="liRightAchievements"><span>
                <span>Achievements</span>
                <img class="removeImg" src="../Images/RemoveButton.ico" /></span></li>
            <li id="liRightMemberships"><span>
                <span>Memberships</span>
                <img class="removeImg" src="../Images/RemoveButton.ico" /></span></li>
            <li id="liRightGetRatings"><span>
                <span>Get Ratings</span>
                <img class="removeImg" src="../Images/RemoveButton.ico" /></span></li>
            <li id="liRightSkills"><span>
                <span>Skills</span>
                <img class="removeImg" src="../Images/RemoveButton.ico" /></span></li>
        </ul>
```

I am trying like this :

```
    function ShowRightCheckMarkButton(Descriptions, Skills, Client, Achievements, Memberships, OrgChart, Specialization,GetRatings) {
            $('.divright').css("visibility", "visible");
            $('#listProjectRelated').empty();
            if (Achievements) {
                $('#listProjectRelated').append("<li id='liRightAchievements'><span><span>Achievements</span><img class='checkImg' src='../Images/Checkmark.ico'/></span></li>")
            }
            else
            {
                $('#listProjectRelated').append("<li id='liRightAchievements'><span><span>Achievements</span><img class='removeImg' src='../Images/RemoveButton.ico'/></span></li>")
            }
.
.
.
.
.
.

    }
```

Comment: What jquery code have you tried?

Comment: Your jquery contains a class (.divright) and an id (#listProjectRelated) that are not in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your function reference an id 'listProjectRelated' in the line:

```
$('#listProjectRelated').empty();
```

should this be the id of the ul element?
So the first line of your html should be

```
<ul id="listProjectRelated">
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/44he8/). One problem with the way you describe the desired function is that you're passing in variable names — I assume these are intended to be strings.

In pseudo-code, what you're trying to achieve is (I think):

1. Grab all the lis.
2. For each of them, see if its text matches any of the arguments ('Client', 'Descriptions'):
3. If so, change the image in the li to display the icon you mentioned (and make sure the image is showing).
4. If not, remove the li from the list.

The code for the function you're looking to call would be like this:

```
function ShowCheckMarkLi(){
    // Get all the lis
    var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

    // Loop through them...
    for(var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; ++i){
        // And, for each, loop through the arguments
        for(var j = 0, m = arguments.length; j < m; ++j){
            // If the argument string is found in the li's text...
            if(lis[i].innerText.match(arguments[j])){
                // ...Find the image
                var img = lis[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
                // ...Change its src attribute to replace all the text after the last slash with your filename
                img.src.replace(/[^\/]+$/, 'CheckmarkImage.Ico');
                // ...And make sure it's displayed.
                img.style.display = 'inline-block';
            }
            // Otherwise...
            else {
                // ...Remove it!
                lis[i].parentNode.removeChild(lis[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Call your function with strings
ShowCheckMarkLi('Descriptions','Client');
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/8YXDJ/

```
    function ShowLi(val) {
        $("#_ul li").css('display','none');
        $(val).each(function() { 
            var t = String(this);
            $("#_ul li span").filter(function() {
                return (jQuery.trim($(this).text()) == t);
            }).parent().css('display','');
        });
    }
ShowLi([ "Descriptions","Specialization","Skills" ])
```